# Navigation bar subtitle is not loading correctly after view is reloaded

Tags: ios, swift, uinavigationbar

When the view is loaded for the first time, the subtitle on the navigation bar loaded correctly and was showing the date without being cut off or anything. When I go into another view, then return to the home view, the subtitle and title of the navigation bar is cut off and is not appearing correctly. Any reason this is caused?

```swift
let dateFormatter = DateFormatter()

dateFormatter.dateStyle = .full
dateFormatter.timeStyle = .full
dateFormatter.dateFormat = "EEEE, dd MMMM"

let dateString = dateFormatter.string(from: date)

self.navigationItem.titleView = setTitle(title: "Home", subtitle: dateString)
```

Showing Correctly:
[image]

Not showing Correctly:
[image]

Comment: Are you changing navigation title style like large or small from another VC check it.

Comment: The Navigation title on the second VC is a large title, is this what might be causing it?

Comment: No, i think you need large title.

Comment: Yes, I've got a large title on my second VC. The nav title is still showing up cut off after leaving the second VC.